# Client config values not being displayed on console

Tags: apache-kafka, slf4j

I am using kafka 3.4.0 and sl4j API 2.0.7. After upgrade SL4j-api to 2.0.7 . kafka client config values not able to display on console. is there any compatibility issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply replace logging JAR files. Kafka source code is compiled with specific packages. `reload4j` for example is what is actually responsible  for the logging, not only `slf4j`

Besides, you should not expect to upgrade a major version of any library and expect it continue to work. If you want to see compatibility issues, read the slf4j release notes.